# return key misregistering as "p" or "l" on iOS 6.1 using SDL 1.3

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, sdl

I'm using SDL 1.3 on iOS 6.1 (on an iPad mini). However when I press the return key it is sometimes misread as "p" or "l".

If I change the keyboard to another language and back to US English again the problem goes away and I never see "p" or "l" entered when I press return.

I can actually see that the "p" key is highlighted even though I'm pressing the return key. Can anyone suggestion a fix or workaround?

Comment: Could be anything really...
Post your code...

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this issue, my write up is here, it's partly my fault for hacking around with the SDL:

http://41j.com/blog/2013/02/iphone-sdl-1-3-sdl2-keyboard-disappearing-and-misregistration-issues/